# Stalling / Won't start

Tags: ford, stall, focus

2010 Ford Focus. Car stalls when running air conditioner; running 55 mph,and car shuts off, not good.. Car won't start when it gets hot. On going. Changed crank shaft sensor twice, relay switch in in fuse box.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any check engine lights? If so, what are they? If not running the AC, this doesn't happen? How long does it take for the vehicle to be able to start again? When it quits, does everything die, or does the engine just stop? Have you checked the fuel pressure? What else have you done to figure out what's going on?

Comment: My Son had one that year and it died on the freeway several times, wound up it was a  bad fuel pump.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bad A/C compressor. If the A/C compressor is binding up, possibly due to a lack of lubrication, internal wear or an over-charged A/C system (too much refrigerant), it may be lugging down the engine when it is engaged